# rsyslog rewrite hostname before relay

Tags: rsyslog

I am setting up rsyslog in a multitenant environment to relay to a central server. Because it is multitenanted, I would like to prefix the hostname from the first rsyslog server with a customer specific prepend before relaying on to the central server. I had planned to set the prefix manually, however, the prefix is configured in another file on the server, and if this could be gathered from that file, that would be even better.

Because the first server will be relaying from multiple hosts, the prepend has to be a dynamic rewrite that includes the original hostname rather than a hard-coded overwrite of the same hostname for all entries, which I've seen in some examples.

Ideally, what I am trying do do is summarised by the following pseudocode:

```
ruleset(name="myrule"){
    set $hostname = "<prefix>-%HOSTNAME%"
    action(type="omfwd" target="remote-ip")
}
```

I will be responsible for both the intermediate relay and the central server, but each relay can host multiple customers, so I don't think that the rewrite can be done on the central server, but I have full control of both layers. Each customer is connected via a dedicated interface and I was planning for a separate ruleset attached to an input configured for each interface and the ruleset to include the customer specific prefix. For this reason, I think the config needs to be on the relay, but if there's a different way, then I am willing to try anything that meets the end-goal of making events customer-identifiable.

The reason for wanting to use the hostname rewrite is because this is in-line with how other tools are configured in the environment and it is highly desirable to keep a homogenous setup. However, if that is not possible, another method may be considered if the first is not technically feasible.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by *dynamic*? Should it read the prefix from another file? Also, to which servers do you have access? And does the config need to be on the "relay" server?

Comment: Thanks @eDonkey. I've updated the question to address your questions. Hopefully this adds the appropriate level of clarity required.

Comment: What kind of data do you receive - to differentiate the clients - when you receive logs on the relay server? Do they all have a unique hostname, or how do you know from which client the logs are?

Comment: Yes, each end-client has a different hostname, e.g. site1-sw1 or site2-rtr2. However, the problem then is that the customer prefix is not in the name as that is our reference for knowing what customer the device relates to. In other systems we rename these names as  cust1-site1-sw1 and cust1-site2-rtr2, especially as there may be a cust2-site2-rtr2, for example. Each customer connects via a different interface on the server that will act as relay.

Comment: I think i understand the problem. Can the server that renames the clients act as the relay? Or is it possible to make it use it in-between the client and relay server? 
Also, I'm sorry to inform you now, but StackOverflow isn't really the right exchange site for this type of questions. It probably be much better off on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/)

Comment: I think it best if the relay renames the clients because by the time it gets to the central server the customer specific information would be lost (each relay can host multiple clients), unless another method was available. Wrt ServerFault, what is best practice: close this question and open a new or leave as-is?

Comment: I guess I will have to think about it too. Doesn't seems too trivial to me. But i'll for sure tag along on ServerFault.

Comment: Yes exactly. Be sure to include all the information from the current post - as well as from the comments, as they answered a lot of question I initially had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question ended up being surprisingly simple. I injected a constant value in to the template like so:

```
template(name="ForwardFormat" type="list") {
    constant(value="<")
    property(name="pri")
    constant(value=">")
    property(name="timestamp" dateFormat="rfc3339")
    constant(value=" ")

    constant(value="myprefix-")

    property(name="hostname")
    constant(value=" ")
    property(name="syslogtag" position.from="1" position.to="32")
    property(name="msg" spifno1stsp="on" )
    property(name="msg")
    }
```